# how to use Best In Place with twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, best-in-place, bootstrap-typeahead

I haven't seen any documentation from this..

If I have

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :city,  type=> :input, %>
```

I need to include the data-provide="typeahead"

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :city, type=> :input,:data => {:provide => "typeahead"} %>
```

and to include the source

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :city, :type=> :input, :data => {:provide => "typeahead", :source => City.getcities.to_json} %>
```

assume `City.getcities.to_json` returns a proper json list with city names

This doesn't work...

Comment: You can try with `<%= best_in_place @user, :city, :type=> :input, :html_attrs => {:'data-provide' => "typeahead", :'data-source' => City.getcities.to_json} %>`

Comment: this is an improvement. Seems to work, but only if I pick from the list with the keyboard and not with the mouse.. is this a typeahead issue?

Comment: seems to be a bootstrap issue https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4018

Comment: I'm not able to try it out, so it can be really that issue in bootsrap or it can be some conflict with best_in_place because best_in_place also subscribes on the input blur and keyup events...

Comment: `$('ul.typeahead').live('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});` seems to handle it

Comment: I've summarized our comments into an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `:data` option you can set the `data-` attibutes on the generated `span` and not on the `input` itself.

If you want to add attributes on the generated `input` element you need to use the `:html_attrs` options:

```
<%= best_in_place @user, :city, :type=> :input, 
    :html_attrs => {:'data-provide' => "typeahead", 
                    :'data-source' => City.getcities.to_json} %>
```

However - as [@Nick Ginanto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972789/nick-ginanto) pointed out - the typeahead selection only works with using the keyboard and not with the mouse (maybe because of a [bug in bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4018) or because there is [no official support](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/212) in best in place for bootstrap)

But the following code snippet seems to solve this issue:

```
$('ul.typeahead').live('mousedown', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: regarding the mouse issue, the above solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: well, the reason why the list disappears on mouseover is here in `bootstrap-typeahead.js`, `mouseleave()` function on the `li`: `if (!this.focused && this.shown) this.hide()`, the list gets hidden as the best_in_place input field is focused, not the list. commented out that line is enough for me.