# Rails + best_in_place + Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, best-in-place

I have really annoying issue with best in place and Twitter bootstrap. I have spent with that a lot of time. I have gone through several pages - best_in_place github page and Issues. So I thought, that I fixed it but not and I don't know where the mistake is.

When I'm using best_in_place for the first edit, it works, save the value and the input is changed back to the "normal" view with new value. But when I want to do the same action( edit it) second time, its not working. I have to reload the page and then I can edit it again only once. My code is bellow:

**AccountsController.rb**

```
def update
    @account = current_user.account
    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@account) }
      else
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@account) }
      end
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= best_in_place current_user.account, :introduction, :type=> :input,
        :nil => "Click me to add your introduction!", 
                :html_attrs => {:'data-provide' => "typeahead" } %>
```

**account.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

I have already seen this pages and haven't found the answer:
[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796415/how-to-use-best-in-place-with-twitter-bootstrap), [ExampleApp](https://github.com/fiedl/best_in_place_typeahead_example), [Best_in_place Issue](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/212)

Please, could someone help me? I know that is maybe caused by Twitter Bootstrap, but I don't know how to fix it:(

Comment: For the second time do input boxes come in best in place?

Comment: I found the answer. Please check the answer below.

Comment: This is not caused by twitter bootstrap. All bootstrap does is apply styling to elements. Based on Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3, you need `respond_with_ip(@object)` for it to work.

Comment: This is 2,5 years old question. I think that this comment is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found the solution for that.
The "issue" is in this line:

```
format.json { respond_with_bip(@account) }
```

I replaced it with:

```
format.json { render json: @account}
```

And its working now. But it was just luck. Do anyone know what is the  main difference here? Why one is working and the second no? What exatly the respond_with_bip does?

Comment: BIP is simply doing an AJAX call to your update action. The render json allows the controller to return the value to your review. Best in PLace is simply putting a AJAX layer on your view -- so from a controller level, there's nothing specific to BIP, so rendering json is all that's needed.